# How to convert x values from dbeta plot into percentage using base r?

Tags: r, plot, distribution, percentage, beta-distribution

I have the plot below using

```
curve(dbeta(x, 81, 219))
```

Now, I want to convert the X values into x*100.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this something you want?

```r
x <- curve(dbeta(x, 81, 219))
# x$x
# $x
# [1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12
# [14] 0.13 0.14 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.20 0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24 0.25
# [27] 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.29 0.30 0.31 0.32 0.33 0.34 0.35 0.36 0.37 0.38
# [40] 0.39 0.40 0.41 0.42 0.43 0.44 0.45 0.46 0.47 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.51
# [53] 0.52 0.53 0.54 0.55 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59 0.60 0.61 0.62 0.63 0.64
# [66] 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69 0.70 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74 0.75 0.76 0.77
# [79] 0.78 0.79 0.80 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84 0.85 0.86 0.87 0.88 0.89 0.90
# [92] 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1.00
# 
#
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

x$x <- x$x*100
x$x
# x$x
# [1]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
# [18]  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
# [35]  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
# [52]  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67
# [69]  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
# [86]  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then you can do

```r
plot(x, type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab = "dbeta(x,81,219")
```

## Output

[image: sample_out]

Comment: I want to draw the plot with x replaced by x*100

Comment: Yap, that'll do.